# Calling SYSTEM$WAIT() with function call as a parameter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Since

```sql
SELECT TYPEOF(1); --INTEGER
SELECT TYPEOF(uniform(1, 10, random())); --INTEGER
```

Why can I run `SYSTEM$WAIT(1)` and it works fine but running `SYSTEM$WAIT(uniform(1, 10, random()))` yields the following error:

```
invalid value [UNIFORM(1, 10, RANDOM())] for parameter 'time'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some functions simply do not accept expressions that are not "constant". One way to circumvent it is usage of session variables:

```
SET val = (SELECT uniform(1, 10, random()));

SELECT SYSTEM$WAIT($val);
```

Output:

[image]

or SQL Scripting block:

```
BEGIN
   LET val := (SELECT uniform(1, 10, random()));
   RETURN SYSTEM$WAIT(:val);
END;
```

[image]